# Call HttpPut with parameter C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I create an `HttpPut` method in an `ASP.NET web api`.

```
[Route("api/Account/Save")]
[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult SaveAccount(Account acc) {
   // do stuff
}
```

I pass in an instant of the `Account` class.

```
class Account
{
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to call this from a console application. I am trying to do this but it's not working. It's not throwing any exception either.

```
var acc = new Account() { AccountID = 1234, AccountName = "zzzzP" };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(acc);
HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
response = await client.PutAsync("api/Account/Save", content);
```

Json returned:

```
"{\"AccountID\":1234,\"AccountName\":\"zzzzP\"}"
```

Comment: throw a break point after serializing the json and see what the value of the json is?

Comment: I just updated the json in the post

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this

```
static async Task PutAccount()
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://yourWebSite.com");
        var acc = new Account() { AccountID = 1234, AccountName = "zzzzP" };
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(acc);                
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync("api/Account/Save", new StringContent(json)))
        {
            return response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
    }
}
```